# How to solve expressions from a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of expressions (+ - *):
`["2 + 3", "5 - 1", "3 * 4", ...]`
and I need to convert every expresion to `expression = answer` like this `2 + 3 = 5`.

I tried just doing `print(listt[0])` but it outputs `2 + 3`, not `5`. So how do i get the answer of this expression? I know that there is a long way by doing `.split()` with  every expression, but is there any other faster way of doing this?

UPD: I need to use only built-in functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string) - There's a lot better answer there in my opinion, which doesn't use eval.

Comment: If the expressions only contain a single operator (e.g., +, -, /, *) you will learn a lot more by trying to do this without *eval()*. You'll learn even more if there are multiple operators and you have to implement BODMAS rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `eval()` function from Python Builtins :

```
for expr in yourlist:
    print(expr, "=", eval(expr))
    # 2+3 = 5
```

As stated in the comments, this is not malicious-proof. Use this only if you know the string being evaluated are indeed simple arithmetic expressions.

Comment: I added a disclamer to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! There are only expressions in the list, so there should not be any problems :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using *eval()* (and you probably should) then you could do something like this:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv
from re import compile

OMAP = {
    '+': add,
    '-': sub,
    '*': mul,
    '/': truediv
}

pattern = compile(r'^(\d+\.*\d*)\s*(.)\s*(\d+\.*\d*)$')

exprs = ["2 + 3.5", "5 - 1", "3 * 4", "3 / 4"]

def convert(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return float(s)

for expr in exprs:
    x, o, y = pattern.findall(expr)[0]
    r = OMAP[o](convert(x), convert(y))
    print(f'{expr} = {r}')
```

**Output:**

```
2 + 3.5 = 5.5
5 - 1 = 4
3 * 4 = 12
3 / 4 = 0.75
```

**Note:**

This is **not** robust as it assumes that the operators are only ever going to be one of +, -, *, / and furthermore that the pattern always matches the regular expression.

Input data changed to include a floating point number

Answer (score 0):

Use eval() function. The eval() function evaluates the specified expression, if the expression is a legal Python statement, it will be executed.